# IPTVs on home network

Tags: networking, home-networking

I have three IP TV boxes in my home that need direct access to my Internet provider. But I need everything else to be run through my router. I can't just hardwire the ports the IPTV boxes are on to the outside because those ports are connected to switches that also have my wifi and media streaming devices on them.

For example, I have this configuration in my living room:

```
|-----BASEMENT---------------|------------LIVING ROOM---------------------------|
Internet -> router -> switch -> switch -> [ IPTV, Roku, Home Wifi, Game Console ]
```

My Internet provider gives me a total of 4 addresses:

- 1 IP address for my Internet use
- 1 IP address specially assigned to each of my 3 IPTV boxes

What router feature do I need to configure to say that the devices with the IPTVs' MAC addresses are special and should not be part of my internal network, but allowed direct access to the outside?

Comment: How are the IPTV boxes are connected to the switch? If they are connected using wireless, your Wireless AP MAY have "Guest" wireless feature which can do AP isolation, so they can access internet, but they can't access the internal network. If they are all wired.. ... uh... VLAN is the only thing I can think of but often not available on home-use switch..

Comment: They're wired. I can load DD-WRT on the router, but my research in to VLANs suggests it's a port-based solution. I may have many things on that port that I want on my home network and not directly accessing the Internet.

Comment: When you say direct access to your internet provider, do you mean they can't be NATted through the Router ? I'm curious as to why they need direct access to your ISP.

Comment: Yes, they need direct access and cannot be NATted. I don't know exactly what services they require, but at boot they have to call home and they can't do that through my router (there is a non-helpful error message about being unable to contact a server).

Comment: Unless your ISP provides you with a few IP addresses, I don't think you're going to have much luck. For all 3 of them to have direct access to the internet, they are going to need 3 separate IP addresses. Alternatively, you could do them one at a time by putting them into the Router's DMZ.

Comment: I get 1 IP address for my Internet use (the reason I need the router). Each IPTV box also gets an address provided my my ISP. All the routers I've seen only provide for 1 DMZ. Also, the DMZ is based on IP address, so the router would have to assign the IPTV an IP address rather than my ISP assigning it. Is there a router model that doesn't have these DMZ limitations?

Comment: Ah I see, so the IPTV boxes are special in that they can connect direct to the ISP ? How do you get internet ? ADSL ? Cable ? 3G ?

Comment: My Internet is FTTH.

Comment: Can you plug ethernet into the NTP for FTTH ? You may be able to just plug a switch in before your router, and plug the IPTV boxes into that.

Comment: No, the IPTV boxes are on the same wire as other things that I want to keep within my network. (See diagram)